# How can I add a floorplan image in rviz?

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, rviz, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to be able to add a floorplan image in rviz simply to debug localization. My map is feature-based, so the image would have no other purpose than to make visualization richer.

Is it possible to obtain a result similar to what is observed with the [DisplayTypes/Map](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Map) without having to publish `nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid` messages? If not, could anyone give me any pointers as to how I would be able to write such a rviz plugin myself?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48489/how-can-i-add-a-floorplan-image-in-rviz?/) by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1264 on 2012-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This appears to be related to [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/40913/draw-image-in-rviz-3d-vizualization-frame/)

I suppose you could publish a [rviz display marker](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Mesh_Resource_.28MESH_RESOURCE.3D10.29_.5B1.1.2B-.5D)  with a custom texture.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2012-11-17**:
This looks like it could work. I will try that and accept your answer if I have good results.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know I'm not answering your direct question, but couldn't you use the map_server (http://ros.org/wiki/map_server) node, remap /map to something else like /map_vis, and then use RViz to just visualize that map  without interfering with anything else in your system?

---

Originally posted by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) with karma: 765 on 2012-11-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2012-11-17**:
Interesting solution! I wouldn't really want to have map_server to interpret occupancy values by thresholding the image though, since there are a few things that are written/drawn on it that are not physical objects. I'm sure this will help others, though!